# For what $n$ is $A_n$ a marginal subgroup of $S_n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, characteristic-subgroups

For what $n$ is $A_n$ a marginal subgroup of $S_n$? Strict definition of marginal subgroups and brief overview of their properties can be found [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Marginal_subgroup)

What have I tried:

$A_n$ is characteristic in $S_n$ for all $n$ as it is its only subgroup of index $2$. Thus the fact that each marginal subgroup is characteristic will not help us to screen out anything.

Thus, we may probably consider some stronger properties, such as, for example, [direct power closed characteristicity](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Direct_power-closed_characteristic_subgroup)... However, I failed to achieve any success in that direction.

Also, for $n = 2$, $A_n$ is the trivial subgroup and thus indeed marginal. However, that does not tell us anything about $n > 2$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n>2$, $A_n$ is not marginal.

Suppose it were, for a word $w$. Any two conjugate elements $x,x'\in S_n$ have the same parity, so there are elements $a,b\in A_n$ such that $x'=ax=xb$. So $w(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is fixed by conjugation (of $x_1,\dots,x_n$, and hence of $w(x_1,\dots,w_n)$) by any element of $S_n$. Hence $w$ can only take values in the centre of $S_n$, which is trivial for $n>2$.